# Regular Expression: Detect Specific String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to search a string in PHP using `preg_match()`, to return a string that takes the format of 'xdr', where x is a single digit.

The string is otherwise made of characters, numbers, '.' full stops and spaces.

I'm hopeless with regular expressions, can somebody help me out?

I've tried `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s2dr$` but it doesn't work

For example, the string might look like `A really big 2.0 was 3dr once`

Comment: Can you show some examples of strings you expect to match and not match?

Comment: What exactly are you tring to catch in that example string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your needs, this regex will work to match a string that contains some number followed by `dr`:

```
 /\b\d+dr\b/
```

in action in `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('/\b\d+dr\b/', $string);
```

**explanation:**

```
/      : regex delim
  \b   : word boundary
  \d+  : one or more digit
  dr   : literaly dr
  \b   : word boundary
/      : regex delim
```

If you want the other characters to be only `characters, numbers, '.' full stops and spaces` use this:

```
preg_match('/^[\w\d. ]*\b\d+dr\b[\w\d. ]*$/', $string);
```

And, to be unicode compatible:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\pN. ]*\b\pN+dr\b[\pL\pN. ]*$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

The following regex will match a single digit followed by *one or more* alpha characters, numbers, full stops and spaces, and ends in `dr`.

```
^\d[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+dr$
```

**Note**: Not sure if you want the literal `dr`, if not, drop it from the end.